# Removing an entire PHP function based on its suffix

Tags: php, parsing

I want to remove all functions ending with `_example` from my code. I am processing the code using `token_get_all`. The code I currently have is below to change the opening tags and strip the comments out.

```
foreach ($files as $file) {
    $content = file_get_contents($file);
    $tokens = token_get_all($content);
    $output = '';

    foreach($tokens as $token) {
        if (is_array($token)) {
            list($index, $code, $line) = $token;

            switch($index) {
                case T_OPEN_TAG_WITH_ECHO:
                    $output .= '<?php echo';
                    break;
                case T_COMMENT:
                case T_DOC_COMMENT:
                    $output .= '';
                    break;
                case T_FUNCTION:
                    // ???
                default:
                    $output .= $code;
                break;
            }
        } else {
            $output .= $token;
        }
    }

    file_put_contents($file, $output);
}
```

I just can't figure out how I can modify it to strip entire functions based on their names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I wrote the new code for your problem:

First, he finds every functions and them declarations in your source code.
Second, he checks if function name finished by "_example" and remove his code.

```
$source = file_get_contents($filename); // Obtain source from filename $filename
$tokens = token_get_all($source); // Get php tokens

// Init variables
$in_fnc    = false;
$fnc_name  = null;
$functions = array();

// Loop $tokens to locate functions
foreach ($tokens as $token){
    $t_array = is_array($token);
    if ($t_array){
        list($t, $c) = $token;
        if (!$in_fnc && $t == T_FUNCTION){ // "function": we register one function start
            $in_fnc   = true;
            $fnc_name = null;
            $nb_opened = $nb_closed = 0;
            continue;
        }
        else if ($in_fnc && null === $fnc_name && $t == T_STRING){ // we check and store the name of function if exists
            if (preg_match('`function\s+'.preg_quote($c).'\s*\(`sU', $source)){ // "function function_name ("
                $fnc_name = $c;
                continue;
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        $c = $token; // single char: content is $token
    }

    if ($in_fnc && null !== $fnc_name){ // we are in declaration of function
        $nb_closed += substr_count($c, '}'); // we count number of } to extract later complete code of this function
        if (!$t_array){
            $nb_opened += substr_count($c, '{') - substr_count($c, '}'); // we count number of { not closed (num "{" - num "}")
            if ($nb_closed > 0 && $nb_opened == 0){ // once "}" parsed and all "{" are closed by "}"
                if (preg_match('`function\s+'.preg_quote($fnc_name).'\s*\((.*\}){'.$nb_closed.'}`sU', $source, $m)){
                    $functions[$fnc_name] = $m[0]; // we store entire code of this function in $functions
                }
                $in_fnc = false; // we declare that function is finished
            }
        }
    }
}

// Ok, now $functions contains all functions found in $filename

$source_changed = false; // Prevents re-write $filename with the original content 
foreach ($functions as $f_name => $f_code){
    if (preg_match('`_example$`', $f_name)){
        $source = str_replace($f_code, '', $source); // remove function if her name finished by "_example"
        $source_changed = true;
    }
}
if ($source_changed){
    file_put_contents($filename, $source); // replace $filename file contents
}
```